# How to select OS during boot?

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-7, hard-drive, ssd

I have laptop with hdd and installed windows 7 on it. I bought ssd drive and replaced it with hdd and installed ubuntu 14.04 on it. I also replaced my cd drive with hdd. So, now, at bios I can select from which device I want to boot and depending on it Ubuntu 14.04 or Windows 7 will be loaded. When you have one hard drive and 2 OS on it, at grub you can choose which OS you want to start.

Is there any way how can I enable such grub menu for Ubuntu 14.04 on SSD and Windows 7 on HDD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set bios to boot from the disk where Ubuntu is installed.

Then run `sudo update-grub` in Ubuntu.

You will have options in grub menu.